# Safer way of constructing LPWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks

I'm using the WinAPI [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) function that requires a `LPWSTR` and am wondering if there is a safer way to do this to ensure there is no memory leak.

Currently I construct an initial pointer to a buffer `buf` using:

```
auto buf = GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, nullptr);
```

Then I create the LPWSTR to be used in lieu of the null pointer in my actual call using:

```
auto driveStrings = static_cast<LPWSTR>(malloc((buf + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)));
```

Next I create a pointer to `driveStrings` to free it later. After checking if `driveStrings` is a null pointer or if the buffer (`buf`) is `NULL` (in case memory couldn't be allocated), I call `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` using `driveStrings`.

After I get the result I manually `free()` the LPWSTR using the pointer I made after allocating it.

How can I use a smart pointer for LPWSTR instead so I don't have to use `malloc()` and `free()`, but so that it will still work with the [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) function?

**Mininum working example:**

```
    auto buf = GetLogicalDriveStrings(0, nullptr);

    auto driveStrings = static_cast<LPWSTR>(malloc((buf + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)));
    auto pDriveStrings = driveStrings;

    if (driveStrings == nullptr || buf == NULL)
    {
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg << "Can't allocate memory for drive list: ";
        msg << GetLastError();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // get drive strings
    if (GetLogicalDriveStrings(buf, driveStrings) == NULL)
    {
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg << "GetLogicalDriveStrings error: ";
        msg << GetLastError();
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    // iterate over results
    while (*driveStrings)
    {
        // GetDriveType() requires a LPCWSTR
        if (GetDriveType(driveStrings) == DRIVE_FIXED || GetDriveType(driveStrings) == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
        {
            std::wcout << driveStrings << std::endl;
        }
        driveStrings += lstrlen(driveStrings) + 1;
    }

    free(pDriveStrings);
```

If I use a `std::wstring`, I can't figure out how to iterate over each string in the `driveStrings` buffer. If I use a `std::vector<WCHAR>`, I can't figure out how to cast each element to an LPCWSTR for `GetDriveType()`.

This works fine as is, but is there a better/safer way to do this? I'm open to any and all improvements.

Comment: `std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(buf + 1);`

Comment: `std::wstring` is also safe in C++11 if used properly.

Comment: The code is faulty anyway.  You are using `malloc`, and potentially `throw`-ing before you even get to call `free()`.

Comment: Besides, your calls to `GetLastError()` are useless. You are meant to call `GetLastError` **immediately** after the conditions are met, where it returns a meaningful value. Don't ever intersperse it with random code that might alter the value.

Comment: so would I just do a static cast to LPWSTR then? (it says no suitable conversion...)

Comment: `std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(buf + 1); GetLogicalDriveStrings(buffer.size(), buffer.`[`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)`);`.

Comment: Alternative to vector: `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer( new wchar_t[ buf + 1 ] ); GetLogicalDriveStrings( buf + 1, buffer.get() );` ...btw I wouldn't name a variable that contains a buffer size `buf`. Better name would be `bufSize` ...

Comment: Please post some of these as answers. I've added to the MWE how I currently iterate over the returned result.

Comment: If I use a `std::wstring`, I can't figure out how to iterate over each string in the `driveStrings` buffer. If I use a `std::vector<WCHAR>`, I can't figure out how to cast each element to an LPCWSTR for `GetDriveType()`.

Comment: There are a maximum of 26 drive letters, 4 characters per drive plus a final null-termination. `wchar_t buffer[105];` is all you need.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That kind of recommendation is what keeps the Windows API from ever evolving. It's what has brought us multiple functions that all do essentially the same, and an impenetrable web of interrelated group policies, system settings, and application manifest entries.

Comment: @IInspectable you can't blame users taking shortcuts when the API has been badly designed in the first place.

Comment: @zett42: Irrespective of how poorly designed you believe an API to be, you still need to adhere to its documented interface. There is no documented limit on the return buffer size. Don't invent one. And since you believe the API were poorly designed, how would you improve it?

Comment: _you still need to adhere to its documented interface_ True. _How would you improve it?_ Propably not the right place here to discuss.

Comment: The limitation is the number of letters in the English alphabet. That isn't something Microsoft control.

Comment: @IInspectable That is [not a valid closure reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1157100) according to the rules in the [help/on-topic]. Please explain why this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and why it is "Code Review material".

Comment: @200_success: At the time I voted to close the question, it was presented as *"working code"*, requesting improvement suggestions, without identifying a specific issue. That's off-topic, and a valid reason to have the question closed. Your meta entry agrees with that, and your only fuss is, that this is neither explicitly spelled out in the help center, nor is there a single-click close reason available. That doesn't make it an invalid closure reason.

Comment: @IInspectable "How can I use a smart pointer for LPWSTR instead so I don't have to use malloc() and free(), but so that it will still work with the GetLogicalDriveStrings() function?" was sufficient to make it an on-topic Stack Overflow question, regardless of whatever working or broken code may have been included.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The limitation is the number and length of [MS-DOS device names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363908.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: MS-DOS device names are drive letters from A: to Z:. This is unlikely to ever change.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: MS-DOS device names **for drives** are drive letters from A: through Z:. Still, the likelihood for change should not make you suggest practices that will prevent change. And really, it doesn't buy you **anything** in the broader sense. This may be a cool trick you can pull on this specific API call. But what about all other API calls, where you cannot do this? Are you going to introduce two ways of doing the same thing, depending on the API you call? Is this going to make your code more readable? Is this not going to be a red herring in debug sessions?

Comment: @IInspectable: I guess I don't see the point of a convoluted wrapper around an API that doesn't need one. I favour simplicity over C++ purity. This question has not led to a generalised solution for the entire Win32 API, which would actually be useful.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: There's nothing simple about magic numbers. Using `wchar_t buffer[105];` may work, or it may truncate output. I won't know, until I look at the documentation, and try to reconstruct the author's line of thought. Using a dynamically sized container, on the other hand, will always work. And it's immediately visible just by looking at the source. My idea of simple is: Always do the same job the same way. Nothing to do with *"C++ purity"*. Just a fact of life: Developers hate surprises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use a smart pointer for LPWSTR instead so I don't have to
>   use malloc() and free(), but so that it will still work with the
>   GetLogicalDriveStrings() function?

You may use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for that. It can be used to allocate an array of characters like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer( new wchar_t[ size ] );
```

An example showing how to use it with `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` follows. The example also shows how to call `GetLastError()` correctly. It must be called immediately after the function that sets the last error value. Any other system call in between (possibly hidden in C or C++ standard code) may invalidate the last error value. For easier use I have wrapped it into `ThrowLastError()` function but the rules still apply.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

void ThrowLastError( const char* msg ) {
    DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
    throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>( err ), std::system_category(), msg );
}

std::set< std::wstring > GetLogicalDriveSet() {
    // Call GetLogicalDriveStrings() to get required buffer size.
    DWORD bufSize = ::GetLogicalDriveStrings( 0, nullptr );
    if( bufSize == 0 )
        ThrowLastError( "Could not get logical drives" );

    // Allocate an array of wchar_t and manage it using unique_ptr.
    // Make sure to allocate space for last '\0'.
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer( new wchar_t[ bufSize + 1 ] ); 

    // Call GetLogicalDriveStrings() 2nd time to actually receive the strings.
    DWORD len = ::GetLogicalDriveStrings( bufSize, buffer.get() );
    if( len == 0 )
        ThrowLastError( "Could not get logical drives" );

    // In a rare case the number of drives may have changed after 
    // the first call to GetLogicalDriveStrings().
    if( len > bufSize )
        throw std::runtime_error( "Could not get logical drives - buffer size mismatch" );

    std::set< std::wstring > result;

    // Split the string returned by GetLogicalDriveStrings() at '\0'.
    auto p = buffer.get();
    while( *p ) {
        std::wstring path( p );
        result.insert( path );
        p += path.size() + 1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::set< std::wstring > drives;
    try {
        drives = GetLogicalDriveSet();
    }
    catch( std::exception& e ) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Fixed and removable drives:\n";
    for( const auto& drv : drives ) {
        DWORD driveType = ::GetDriveType( drv.c_str() );
        if( driveType == DRIVE_FIXED || driveType == DRIVE_REMOVABLE ){
            std::wcout << drv << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Personally I would go with `GetLogicalDrives()` though which avoids the hassles of buffer management completely. In addition the error handling is simplified because you have to call this function only once. For completeness I'm providing an example how to use `GetLogicalDrives()` below.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

void ThrowLastError( const char* msg ) {
    DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
    throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>( err ), std::system_category(), msg );
}

std::set< std::wstring > GetLogicalDriveSet() {
    std::set< std::wstring > result;

    DWORD mask = GetLogicalDrives();
    if( mask == 0 )
        ThrowLastError( "Could not get logical drives" );       

    for( wchar_t drive = 'A'; drive <= 'Z'; ++drive ) {
        if( mask & 1 ) {
            // Build a complete root path like "C:\\" that can be used
            // with GetDriveType().
            wchar_t path[]{ drive, ':', '\\', 0 };
            result.insert( path );
        }
        // Shift all bits to the right so next "mask & 1" will test for
        // next drive letter.
        mask >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::set< std::wstring > drives;
    try {
        drives = GetLogicalDriveSet();
    }
    catch( std::exception& e ){
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Fixed and removable drives:\n";
    for( const auto& drv : drives ) {
        DWORD driveType = ::GetDriveType( drv.c_str() );
        if( driveType == DRIVE_FIXED || driveType == DRIVE_REMOVABLE ){
            std::wcout << drv << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your downvote so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Why not if it makes the original question obsolete? OP's question comes from using an API that has an easier-to-use alternative so it should be a valid answer to suggest that API and show how to use.

Comment: The OP is asking how to use C++ to close the gap between a C API and automatic memory management. The API called in question is an unrelated artifact. And since this proposed answer doesn't address that question, *"it's not useful"*. That's the tooltip text for the downvote button.

Comment: _call to GetDriveType()_ ...nothing easier than that, added. _The bit shifts/masks are confusing to me and the ':\\' string._ ... added comments.

Comment: Thank you! Any reason in particular to use the std::set over a std::vector in this case?

Comment: Not really. You could simply replace `std::set` by `std::vector` and replace `result.insert()` by `result.push_back()`. I thought a set would be more convenient in general, as it would allow you to look up if a certain drive exists, e.g. `drives.find(L"C:\\")`. Of course you could do that with vector too, using `std::find()` or a simple loop. Just not as convenient ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd do something like this:

```
std::wstring s(buf+1, '\0');

auto len = GetLogicalDriveStrings(buf, &s[0]);
s.resize(len);
```

This creates a `wstring` containing NULs, then `GetLogicalDriveStrings` overwrites the content with what it produces. Finally, we resize the string down to the number of characters that `GetLogicalDriveStrings` actually wrote.

From there, we have a perfectly normal string that will free its memory when it goes out of scope, just like any other string.

Comment: This makes sense, I currently iterate over the returned value by using a while loop `while (*driveStrings) {driveStrings += lstrlen(driveStrings)+1}`. How would I loop over `std::wstring`? Can I split by NUL byte? Or do I need to use `std::vector<WCHAR>` to do that?

Comment: You can iterate of the characters in a string